# Phrase where you flip it and it means something else

Tags: phrases, expressions

In high school a while ago, I learned a bunch of random terms for words and phrases: synecdoche, antonym, oxymoron, palindrome, etc. There's one term that escapes me but I can give examples of it.

> I don't love my wife because she is beautiful but she is beautiful
>   because I love her.
>
> We travel not to escape life, but for life not to escape us.

What is the name of this term? Thanks in advance, it's killing me not being able to remember.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're looking for [***antimetabole***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimetabole), or more generally, [***chiasmus***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiasmus).

My favorite class of these phrases is the Yakov Smirnoff *Russian reversal*:

> In America, you can always find a party. In Soviet Russia, Party always finds you!